# SCSS '@use' not supported in Gulp?

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp

Everything is working fine. The 'import' works fine but '@use' is not working.

> Main SCSS file

```
@use 'colors';
// @import 'colors';

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

  p{
  background-color: $main-color; 
}
```

> scss partial file (_colors.scss)

```
$main-color: #235c4b;
```

The folder structure is correct and it works correctly when using 'import'. Does it mean gulp does not support '@use'?

Comment: I assume you are using `gulp-sass` - it doesn't support `@use`.  Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass `gulp-dart-sass` instead.

Comment: @Mark That worked, thanks a lot. It works when I install it as a dev dependency but got a whole bunch of ERR when I installed it normally, can you explain the cause of the error please?

Comment: I have only installed it locally so I haven't seen any errors.